# Is it possible to rename or define a new name for our office 365 domain

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, domain

Currently we have our domain for example as `abcde.onmicrosoft.com` and then we bought `abcde.com` from  godaggy so users emails does not have to have the `onmicrosoft` inside it, as follow:-

[image]

Now our customer is asking to change the Office 365 domain name from ABCDE to something else.. so the SharePoint site can be accessed using this url `https://NEW NAME.sharepoint.com/`instead of this url `https://ABCDE.sharepoint.com/`.. so is this possible? if renaming is not an option, then can we register the new domain `New Name` inside office 365 and define it as the default domain? so the SharePoint site can be accessed using this url  `https://NEW NAME.sharepoint.com/`instead of this url `https://ABCDE.sharepoint.com/`?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to change the SharePoint domain name for your organization in Microsoft 365. For example, if the name of your organization changes from "**ABCDE**" to "NewName" you can't change `ABCDE.sharepoint.com` to `NewName.sharepoint.com`.

To use the domain name `NewName.sharepoint.com`, you would need to purchase a new Microsoft 365 subscription and move all email, files, and any other data you want to keep to the new subscription.

Note；You can't transfer a Microsoft 365 domain to another registrar for **60 days** after you purchase the domain from Microsoft.

**Refernence:**

- [Change your SharePoint domain name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-your-sharepoint-domain-name)
- [Transfer a domain from Microsoft to another host](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-with-domains/transfer-a-domain-from-microsoft-to-another-host?view=o365-worldwide)

Answer (score 0):

I was poking around in my admin portal recently and noticed Domains. Log in at https://portal.office.com for your admin portal, click on Admin and then look at Domains. This is definitely admin activity.

When in Domains you'll be able to add a domain and will need to add the DNS records with the registrar. Anywhere from 10 minutes to 48 hours those records will validate (assuming they're entered correctly). Then, you'll have that domain accessible by the tenancy. You should then be able to use that registered Domain as your URL. You may even be able to depreciate the old one by removing it from the list of Domains for the tenancy.